# Cant plot the chart line-time-series correctly

Tags: php, highcharts

I´m doing a program and trying put in the chart provides by highcharts, but according to the website example, I´ve done my json on php but at the time to plot it, all the data goes wrong, so I couldn't identify which data are missing to do this chart works properly..

this is the link that has the example => https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/usdeur.json

So, I´d like to know which data is used to get theses values for example=> 1167609600000

my json code, follows this pattern below 
that is the same from the site example:

[[6849547330, 10.96],[6849547390, 11.39],[6849533050, 11.31]]

I don't get any error, but that data that is plotted is wrong.

obs* $data is an array that I´ve the dates on format dd/mm/yyyy

```
foreach ($data as $key) {
    $segundos = strtotime(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($key)));
    array_push($dataNova,$segundos);
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867138/populate-group-data-to-a-particular-series-on-highcharts/57911327#57911327

Comment: thank you for trying help, but this chart that I refer dont use this kind of data like your example, in fact my doubt is only about wich data are used to make this value for example =>1167609600000, just it that I need to know to solve my problem!
I´ve already tried to do like this :

Comment: [code]
foreach ($data as $key) {
    $dof = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($key));
    array_push($dataNova,mktime(
        date("w",strtotime($dof)),
        date("n",strtotime($key)),date("j",strtotime($key)),
        date("Y",strtotime($key))
    ));
}
[/code]
but at the time to plot it things goes wrong :/

Comment: Please create a fiddle for what have you tried and what you want to achieve, as I shared you this answer.

Comment: Based on input required in highcharts and expected graph then only can suggest changes in PHP or js

Comment: this is the default chart => jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/… as you see this data is used => cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/… so my doubt is, what kind of data is it made of?

Comment: Please try to be more precise. What do you mean saying the data is plotted wrongly? Show demo or image where it is correct and how it looks in your example. Or prepare a working demo with your code.

Comment: sorry, im trying to be more clear i can, so, the only thing that i need to understand is, how this data is made?
the data I reffer is on json like this example, a node of that json looks like this => [1167609600000, 0.7537], this first group of numbers before the comma that i need to understand how it is made, because i thought that it was made from date converted to seconds but it isnt, there is something more, and i cant identify yet, the link below shows the example and on the js code has the json link for you see what I said ....

Comment: jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/

so, I hope someone could help, and since now thanks a lot!

Comment: This value is a timestamp in milliseconds since 1970. Check it in the API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.x

Comment: @WojciechChmiel, , thanks for trying to help man, but I´ve alredy thougth about that but when I try to convert the date that I have some results are wrong, in fact it goes with negative value, I have date in this format "dd-mm-yyyy", so I´m doing like this to convert, take a look above on my question obs*

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a PHP expert, I can help you with js. However, it looks like a simple issue.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel thanks man, there´s no problem, I´m not a PHP expert too, so. I can solve my problem with  ewolden user help example in another topic and with one more thing that I found in the internet, so ewolden help me with Js to, on this topic he shows it => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168055/high-charts-time-series-zoomable-not-working-with-my-data?rq=1

Comment: and the other thing that I had to do for it works its here =>https://www.it-swarm.net/pt/php/php-data-que-mostra-1970-01-01-apos-conversao/942636187/   
the date I´ve alredy have must be converted, and has to take it off "/" and put like this "-" instead of, so, I used a simple str_replace to do this, so thanks for all those tried to help me, I really appreciate it, and if this answer could help someone in future I´ll bem happy too :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad your issue is resolved.